# Why is callback undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, constructor, callback

Hello im using an object constructor to manage some animation, in some cases i want to pass a callback when the animation is finished to make some other elements appear. The problem is if out of the if sentence i log a type of callback it is effective a  function but when i do the log inside an if statement if is always undefined, i appreciate if someone could help me with this, i also leave the piece of code so you guys can check it out.

```
// CONSTRUCTOR WHO MANAGE THE ANIMATIONS FOR THE WEBSITE

function SpriteAnimation(frameWidth, spriteWidth, spriteElement, shouldLoop, frameRate){
    this.frameWidth = frameWidth;
    this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
    this.selector = document.getElementById(spriteElement);
    this.shouldLoop = shouldLoop ;
    this.curPx = 0;
    this.frameRate = frameRate;
}

SpriteAnimation.prototype.start = function(callback){
    this.selector.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + this.curPx + "px 0px";
    this.curPx += this.frameWidth;

    if (this.curPx < (this.spriteWidth - this.frameWidth)){
        setTimeout(this.start.bind(this), this.frameRate);
    }else if (this.curPx > (this.spriteWidth - this.frameWidth)){
        console.log(typeof callback);
    }else if(this.shouldLoop){
        this.curPx = 0;
        this.start();
    }
};
```

later in the code I instanced it and run the start:

```
var letter = new SpriteAnimation(790, 18163, "letter", false, 53.3);

letter.start(function(){
    console.log("hola");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one possibility is the start function is invoked by the setTimeout

```
SpriteAnimation.prototype.start = function(callback){
    this.selector.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + this.curPx + "px 0px";
    this.curPx += this.frameWidth;

    if (this.curPx < (this.spriteWidth - this.frameWidth)){
        setTimeout((function(){
            this.start(callback)
        }).bind(this), this.frameRate);
    }else if (this.curPx > (this.spriteWidth - this.frameWidth)){
        console.log(typeof callback);
    }else if(this.shouldLoop){
        this.curPx = 0;
        this.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: i would like to know why inside de setTimeout you wrap the function inside () ...this answer worked very well for me, just want to learn the why of the things

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez because I wanted to call `bind(this)` on the `setTimeout` handler... so just wrapped it inside `()`.  But I would recommend using `$.proxy()` over `.bind()` because of old browser compatibility issues

Comment: using `$.proxy()` like `setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
    this.start(callback);
}, this), this.frameRate);`

Comment: the () make that function a self ejecution function?...sorry english is not my native lenguage

Comment: mm didn't know you can wrap things like that in java script, do you have a resource where i can probably read a bit about it?...also thanks for your help and patience

Answer (score 2):

You did not pass the callback in your `setTimeout`, I would suggest doing this:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.start(callback);
    }, this.frameRate);
```